# php mysql select from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem, I would need to retrieve two values ​​from different tables and compare if they are equal like this.

```
SELECT * FROM front_user WHERE username = (value from admin_user "username")
```

i have tried something like this but with no good result.

```
mysql_query('SELECT * FROM front_user WHERE username = "'.$myValue.'"');
```

I want to know if the value of "username" in the file front_user is the same as the value in the "username" in admin_user file is the same

Comment: Use the [`join()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) function.

Comment: Could you write in ENGLISH please?

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated. Please switch to the mysqli library as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it all in one query -

```
SELECT front_user.* FROM front_user
JOIN admin_user
ON front_user.username = admin_user.username
```

This will return all rows from front_user that has a matching username in admin_user. Then you can add a WHERE clause -

```
WHERE front_user.username = 'foo'
```

Comment: public function getStoresByAuthor($search) 
    {
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT front_user.* FROM front_user
JOIN admin_user
ON front_user.username = admin_user.username');

Comment: i write my code like that and on my site i got an Fatal error message :(

Comment: You forgot your WHERE clause and you changed to PDO in mid-stream. Are you sure you're using PDO correctly? What error did you get?

Comment: it works, i forgot an "s" at front_user..., my misstake! thanks man!!